# Drupal 8 with QuickEdit and restfull view API

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-8

Is it possible to make a QuickEdit to work when fetching a view restfully and make quickedit to work of that response? I have AJAX call that displays taxonomy hooked to a view. The restfull response from the view:

```
[
    {
       "colors": "\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'taxonomy_term' -->\n<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:\n   * taxonomy-term--23.html.twig\n   x taxonomy-term--product-color.html.twig\n   * taxonomy-term.html.twig\n-->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/themes/kasthall/taxonomy-term--product-color.html.twig' -->\n\n    <div class=\"column\">\n        <div class=\"case-column-link\">\n                            \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->\n<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:\n   * field--taxonomy-term--field-taxonomy-image-1--product-color.html.twig\n   * field--taxonomy-term--field-taxonomy-image-1.html.twig\n   * field--taxonomy-term--product-color.html.twig\n   * field--field-taxonomy-image-1.html.twig\n   * field--exigusimage.html.twig\n   x field.html.twig\n-->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->\n\n            <div data-quickedit-field-id=\"taxonomy_term/23/field_taxonomy_image_1/en/default\">\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'exigus_image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/modules/custom/exigus_images/templates/exigus-image.html.twig' -->\n<img src=\"http://kasthall.local/sites/default/files/styles/content_block_thumb_372x372/public/815_ruby-red.jpg?itok=avGWpT-2\" class=\"img-responsive\">\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'sites/all/modules/custom/exigus_images/templates/exigus-image.html.twig' -->\n\n</div>\n      \n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->\n\n\n                        <!-- <span class=\"case-column-header\"></span> -->\n            <span class=\"case-column-body\">\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->\n<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:\n   * field--taxonomy-term--name--product-color.html.twig\n   * field--taxonomy-term--name.html.twig\n   * field--taxonomy-term--product-color.html.twig\n   * field--name.html.twig\n   * field--string.html.twig\n   x field.html.twig\n-->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->\n\n            <div data-quickedit-field-id=\"taxonomy_term/23/name/en/default\">Color red</div>\n      \n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->\n\n</span>\n        </div>\n        <div data-contextual-id=\"taxonomy_term:taxonomy_term=23:changed=1458749911&amp;langcode=en\"></div>\n    </div>\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'sites/all/themes/kasthall/taxonomy-term--product-color.html.twig' -->\n\n"
},...
```

Later when I try to append this `$('.my-div').append(response.colors)` to the dom or even fact to a div that has the contextual region for QuickEdit, it still doesn't shows up. I have tried to look for more documentation and played around with `Drupal.quickedit` with js but with no success.